# iOS Kiwi/Nocilla Tests not calling blocks

Tags: ios, unit-testing, bdd, kiwi, nocilla

I am trying to get familar with the [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi) BDD testing framework. I am using it it in conjuction with [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla) to mock HTTP requests. Both projects look awesome but I am having some difficulty with it. I have the following test spec:

```
    beforeAll(^{ // Occurs once
         [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] start];
    });

    afterAll(^{ // Occurs once
        [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] stop];
    });

    beforeEach(^{ // Occurs before each enclosed "it"
        couch = [[Couch alloc]initWithDatabaseUrl:@"http://myhost/mydatabase"];
    });

    afterEach(^{ // Occurs after each enclosed "it"
        [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] clearStubs];
    });

    it(@"should be initialized", ^{
        [couch shouldNotBeNil];
    });

    context(@"GET requests", ^{
    it(@"should get document by id", ^{
        __block NSData *successJson = nil;
        __block NSError *requestErr = nil;
        stubRequest(@"GET", @"http://myhost/mydatabase/test").
        withHeader(@"Accept", @"application/json").
        withBody(@"{\"_id\":\"test\",\"_rev\":\"2-77f66380e1670f1876f15ebd66f4e322\",\"name\":\"nick\"");

        [couch getDocumentById:@"test" success:^(NSData *json){
            successJson = json;
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            requestErr = error;
        }];

        [[successJson shouldNot]equal:nil];

    });
    });
```

Sorry for the long code snippet. I want to make sure I give context. As you can see I am testing the behavior of an object which makes a GET request and reports the results in a 'success' block and reports errors in a 'failure' block. I have two __block vars to store success and failures receptively. Currently the test checks that the 'success' var has a value (not nil). This test passes. However debugging this test it appears neither blocks are ever executed. The successJson appears nil. I would expect Nocilla to have passed the stub body content to the success block parameter. So is my test constructed incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The general structure of your test looks OK. For [asynchronous testing](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Asynchronous-Testing), use this:

```
[[expectFutureValue(theValue(successJson != nil)) shouldEventually] beTrue];
```

The reason for the `!= nil` and `beTrue` above is that there is no shouldEventually + notBeNil sort of combination that you can use to test for an eventual nil value. The test above will find that `successJson` is initially nil, and thus will continue to poll that value until your callback makes it non-nil.

Note that if you were doing a positive test, such as checking for successJson == @"test", then you could use a simpler form for the expectation:

```
[[expectFutureValue(successJson) shouldEventually] equal:@"test"];
```

Also note that you can use `shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(2.0)` to increase the default timeout (1 second I think) to whatever timeout you want for asynchronous expectations.